# Windows Setup Project without .net dependency

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, installation, platform-independent

I have made a custom dll for my setup project. My dll is very simple, registering few services, not CLR or any 3rd party lib dependent. Have statically linked with msi.lib only.

I have removed the .net and windows installer prerequisite requirements from the setup project. My setup fails on macines not having .net framework..?

As I have not having any .net dependent code, what should be the solution to this. I don;t want user to download framework first for installation.

Regards Amit

Comment: what kind of error appears to you during setup

Comment: Does your application refuse to start showing a dialog "Unable to initalize application (0xc0150002)? If so see: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/a5f3153b-c16d-49f5-992a-aed1daa76496/

Answer (score 2):

Some more information on your build environment will be helpful. Also, check these too:

If you build the project using VC++ 2005 or greater, the appropriate Redistributable Package should be installed on the client system. This is required even if you don't use .NET libraries. ([Google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enIN291IN321&aq=0&oq=VC%2B%2B+runtime+re&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vc%2B%2B+runtime+redistributable))

Make sure you set the project property "General->Common Language Runtime Support" to "No Common Language Runtime support"

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the "Debug" or "Release" version of your application?  "Debug" versions don't work on machines that don't have VS installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have build the project using NO CLR use setting.
Also I am have build it on a development machine with VS 2008 and .net 3.5 Vista OS and testing it on a fresh vista virtual machine with no CLR.

But yes that appropriate Redistributable Package point can be confirmed. Will get back after confirming that.

I had a solution otherwise, using custom exes, which works.

Thanks anyways,
Amit